# How to join 3 select queries?

Tags: sql, database

How to join these 3 queries?

```
select gameid, type, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5 
from tbl_game 
where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + 
      " OR Player4=" + userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No' 

select Player1, Player2, Streaks 
from tbl_streaks 
where gameid = [gameid from first query]

select userid, userid, Facebookid, points 
from tbl_userinfo 
where userid = [players from first query]
```

`userid` is passed as parameter.

I don't have any idea ..

Please help me.

Comment: Well, explain the table structures! What tables are involved? How are they connected, e.g. what FK relationships do you have? E.g. how are `tbl_userinfo` and `tbl_game` related?? That will show you how to join them ...

Comment: Post you table structures. To answer the question we need to see the tables and their relationships to do a proper join.

Comment: The design you have - to have 5 fixed columns in the `tbl_game` table - is a really really bad design. To get all those players, you now potentially have to join to the `tbl_userinfo` table at least five times! You should really look at creating a many-to-many relationship between game and user - using a "link" table to join any number of players to a game. ....

Comment: +1. And it's hard to know what the desired result might be involving first and second table.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want :

```
select g.gameid, g.type, g.Player1, g.Player2, g.Player3, g.Player4, g.Player5, s.Player1, s.Player2, s.Streaks, u.userid, u.Facebookid, u.points
FROM tbl_game g
JOIN ( select Player1, Player2, Streaks from tbl_streaks) s ON s.gameid = g.gameid
JOIN ( select userid, userid, Facebookid, points from tbl_userinfo ) u ON u.userid = (g.Player1 OR g.Player2 OR g.Player3 OR g.Player4 OR g.Player5)
where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + 
      " OR Player4=" + userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No'
```

However it's a bad design having a lot of columns with n player, they should be row of a dedicated table ...

Answer (score 1):

```
select tg.gameid, tg.type, tg.Player1, tg.Player2, tg.Player3, tg.Player4
     , tg.Player5, ts.Streaks, tu.userid, tu.Facebookid, tu.points 
  from tbl_game tg 
 inner join tbl_streaks ts 
    on ts.gameid = tg.gameid 
 inner join tbl_userinfo tu 
    on ( tg.Player1 = tu.userid 
          or tg.Player2 = tu.userid 
          or tg.Player3 = tu.userid 
          or tg.Player4 = tu.userid 
          or tg.Player5 = tu.userid
             )
 where tu.userid = " + userid + " 
   and tg.Complete = 'No';
```

This is as per your table structure but I suggest you to work on schema so that you can make a better optimized query with improved performance. Remove column players from tbl_game and Make a separate look up table for players with reference of userid to tbl_userinfo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select gameid , type ,Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5 from tbl_game 
Natural Join
(select Player1, Player2, Streaks from tbl_streaks) as t4 on t4.gameid=tbl_game.gameid 
Natural Join
(select userid, userid,Facebookid,points from tbl_userinfo) as t5 on t5.userid="+userid+" 
where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + " OR Player4=" +  userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No'
```